# Datatable initialization in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, .net-6.0

I am using DI for getting the Data table. But the difficulty is that the DataTable is re initialized every time and the rows already added are not available.

```
 public  DataTable GetDatatable()
        {
            
            
               
                var dt = new DataTable("test1");
                dt.Columns.Add("signature", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("timestamp", typeof(string));
                return dt;
            
            
            
        }
```

Is there any way we can initialize  data table in the same name only if data table not exists?

Comment: can you show how you are using `DI`? because you should be able to do what you want by injecting a `Singleton` of `DataTable`

Comment: builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITable,Table>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mihail suggested, here is a Singleton (give it a better name)

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> Lazy = new(() => new Singleton());
    public static Singleton Instance => Lazy.Value;
    public DataTable DateTable { get; set; } 

    private Singleton()
    {
        DateTable = new DataTable();
        DateTable.Columns.Add("signature", typeof(string));
        DateTable.Columns.Add("timestamp", typeof(string));
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var dataTable = Singleton.Instance.DateTable;
```